# Variables in sql statement make query hang

Tags: variables, mariadb

the following sql statement delivers what it should. The min value in a defined timeframe.

```
select value, datetime from Schuppen 
where (value = (select min(value) from Schuppen 
    where (measure = 'temp') 
    and datetime between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-11-02 00:00:00')) 
and datetime between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-11-02 00:00:00';
```

When I use a variable, instead of the hardcoded dates, the statement hangs.

```
set @startdate = cast('2018-11-01 00:00:00' as datetime);   
select value, datetime from Schuppen 
where (value = (select min(value) from Schuppen 
    where (measure = 'temp') 
    and datetime between @startdate and '2018-11-02 00:00:00')) 
and datetime between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-11-02 00:00:00';
```

I wonder why this statement does not work against my maria db version 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1.

Tried via the mysql console.

```
mysql --user=XXXX --password=XXXX Outdoor-Air
...
Your MariaDB connection id is 194
Server version: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1

...

MariaDB [Outdoor-Air]> set @startdate = cast('2018-11-01 00:00:00' as datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [Outdoor-Air]> select @startdate;
+---------------------+
| @startdate          |
+---------------------+
| 2018-11-01 00:00:00 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [Outdoor-Air]> select value, datetime from Schuppen where (value = (select min(value) from Schuppen where (measure = 'temp') and datetime between @startdate and '2018-11-02 00:00:00')) and datetime between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-11-02 00:00:00';
```

Now the statement hangs.

Comment: Which version of Mariadb are you using ?

Comment: 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1

Comment: Are you ensuring that both the queries are running in the same session ?

Comment: I started using HeidiSQL Query windows and changed to mysql console, to rule out HeidiSQL. Just types both commands after each other. Or do i have to consider anything else in order to make sure both queries run in the the session?

Comment: Run the `set` and `select` query together in terminal and confirm this behaviour. My doubt is that HeidiSQL might be running these two queries in two different sessions.

Comment: see updated post above

Comment: Checked. I have given an alternate query in the answer (combined them both); you can try that.

Comment: By "hangs", you mean "takes a long time"?  How many rows in the table?  What does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` say for the @ version?

Comment: Why is this question substantively different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53462728/slow-sql-statement-when-using-variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  `value`, `datetime`
    FROM  Schuppen
    WHERE  measure = 'temp'
      AND  `datetime` >= '2018-11-01'
      AND  `datetime` <  '2018-11-01' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
    ORDER BY `value`  ASC
    LIMIT  1;
```

And this should help:

```
INDEX(measure, datetime, value)
```

One potential difference between this formulation and yours:  This will show only one row if the lowest value occurs more than once on that day.

Comment: That's the perfect answer. Avoiding subqueries also allows the usage of variables without optimizer/variable hazzle.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that both the queries, *viz.*, `SET` and `SELECT` statements are running within a same session. `@startdate` will persist across a single session only.

You can also convert these two queries into a single query utilzing `CROSS JOIN` with Derived Table.

```
SELECT value,
       `datetime`
FROM   Schuppen
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @startdate := cast('2018-11-01 00:00:00' as datetime)) vars 
WHERE  ( value = (SELECT Min(value)
                  FROM   Schuppen
                  WHERE  ( measure = 'temp' )
                         AND `datetime` BETWEEN
                             @startdate AND '2018-11-02 00:00:00') )
       AND `datetime` BETWEEN '2018-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-11-02 00:00:00';
```

Comment: I tried your approach (copy paste into sql console) but the effect is the same. The Statement hangs.

Comment: @AndiGasman check the updated query. Added backticks around `datetime` as it is a keyword. I am also not sure about `cast .. as datetime` part. Also casting is not required; it should work as it is

Comment: Hate to say it but same effect with your updated query (with backticks and no cast).

Comment: @AndiGasman is it possible for you to put some sample data in a fiddle ? Sometimes looking at **relevant, minimal yet complete** sample data helps. There is definitely a very minor error getting overlooked. You can setup the fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ and save and share the link with me.

Comment: Nice tool, never heard of it. I put in the create and inserts and my original sql statement with variable on the right and it worked.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=hl4MJkwBtm