# Slow sql statement when using variables

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, variables, mariadb

I have the following SQL statement running against a MariaDB 10.1.26 with ~2.000 rows with instant results.

```
select value, datetime from Schuppen 
where (value = (select min(value) from Schuppen where (measure = 'temp') 
    and datetime between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-11-02 00:00:00')) 
and datetime between '2018-11-01 00:00:00' and '2018-11-02 00:00:00';
```

When I use the following statement with variables for the datetime fields, the execution takes ~5.5 seconds.

```
set @startdate = cast('2018-11-01 00:00:00' as datetime);
set @enddate = cast('2018-11-02 00:00:00' as datetime);
select value, datetime from Schuppen 
where (value = (select min(value) from Schuppen where (measure = 'temp') 
    and datetime between @startdate and @enddate)) 
and datetime between @startdate and @enddate;
```

The more data rows I have, the longer it takes to execute the statement. Seems like the variables change the behaviour of the statement somehow.

What's wrong here?

Comment: Why is this question substantively different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53460954/variables-in-sql-statement-make-query-hang ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the query optimizer does a bad job on finding a suitable index when using variables. This is a known issue.

If you use `EXPLAIN` on both queries, you will see the difference. Just try to avoid variables when not necessary.

For the first query, the optimizer "sees" the chosen values and decides an index can be perfectly used to satisfy the selected range more efficiently.

For the second query, the optimizer is unaware of the two values that define the range, and decides to fall back to a FULL SCAN instead.

Comment: One thing that might affect the optimizer is that user defined variables `@var` do not have datatype datetime. _ User variables can be assigned a value from a limited set of data types: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value._ See [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). Use of variables (use local variables instead) should not affect the optimization as the optimizer can see the values when doing the optimization. Another thing that might explain the difference is the query cache being used in first one.

Comment: @slaakso that's right, it depends on the datatype and how the variable is treated. (Ie usage of functions with indeterminate output) Still I think avoiding the usage is still the correct advice for most cases, because you usually don't need variables when you write SQL queries as part of your application code.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. That point to the root cause. But how do I deal with IN parameters in a stored procedure? My plan was to create a SP and hand over the start and end dates to it. Best practice would be to build the entire SQL statement in the my application code with hardcoded dates and avoid stored procedures, right?

Comment: @AndiGasman well if you want the best performance, this is the way to go. Even prepared statements can cause optimizer index misuse. If you want to learn more about it, I suggest reading "SQL Performance Explained" by Markus Winand.

Answer (score 7):

I use MySQL Workbench and @variables are very useful to query/search different tables for a given attribute. I ran into a similar issue. After scouring through different threads and trying different things, it worked well when I set the @variable to be of exactly the same type *and* same encoding as the column in the table(s) that I am searching for that variable.

For example:

```
SET @keyword = CONVERT(CAST("KEYWORD" AS CHAR(8)) USING ASCII);
```

In this case, the search column cname in my table customer is of type CHAR(8) and encoded using ASCII:

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE cname=@keyword;
```

If you have multiple tables to query, where cname is CHAR(10) in one and CHAR(8) in another, then you can do the following:

```
SET @keyword = "KEYWORD";
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE cname=CONVERT(CAST(@keyword AS CHAR(8)) USING ASCII);
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE cname=CONVERT(CAST(@keyword AS CHAR(10)) USING ASCII);
```

Comment: By "it worked well" do you mean it ran just as fast as not using variables?